# How can I apply two filters simultaneously to the Tweepy Streaming API filter function?

Tags: python, api, tweepy

Im using the Tweepy API to catch new tweets from a specific account with a specific string in it.

What happens is that I add the two filters, but the api doesnt fetch the tweets from that account WITH that string in it. It fetches all tweets with the string and also the tweets from the account.

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)
             
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
myStream.filter(track=["hello"], follow=["19384112"])
```

I tried with two lines

```
myStream.filter(track=["hello"])
myStream.filter(follow=["19384112"])
```

Nothing seems to achieve what I want.